# stats counter taking to much time to finish it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on website in that i have added stats counter that will start counting when user scroll to that specific section but it is taking long time to finished it. I'm not that much good in js and jquery kindly help me with this.
Thanks in advance.
here is my code

```js
$(function () {
    function isScrolledIntoView($elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    function count($this) {
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        if (isScrolledIntoView($this) && !$this.data("isCounting") && current < $this.data('count')) {
            $this.html(++current);
            $this.data("isCounting", true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.data("isCounting", false);
                count($this);
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    $(".statsCounter").each(function () {
        $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
        $(this).html('0');
        $(this).data("isCounting", false);
    });

    function startCount() {
        $(".statsCounter").each(function () {
            count($(this));
        });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        startCount();
    });

    startCount();
});
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 

   
<div class="col-lg-3 stats">
                <img src="https://www.westernrubbers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Molds.jpg">
                 <div class="counter-section"><span class="statsCounter">4000</span>
                                 <h5 style="margin-top:10px"> MOLDS</h5>
                                  </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 stats">
                <img src="https://www.westernrubbers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/user.jpg">              
                                <div class="counter-section"><span class="statsCounter">40</span>
                                 <h5 style="margin-top:10px"> YEARS IN BUSINESS</h5>
                                 </div>
                
            </div>
```

Counter is working fine only issue is taking too much time to finish it.

Comment: what do you mean, but it 's taking too much time to finish? i dont understant...

Comment: counting should finish in 5 secs.

Comment: i dont see the class c-section4 in your html code..just one section?

Comment: i have renamed class to statsCounter and forget to update here but now i have change it. sorry for wrong code.

Comment: how do you calculate the 5sec?

Comment: i didn't get you. The problem is it is taking more than 30 sec to count 4000 instead it should take 5 secs only.

Comment: the time is 200s see my answer

Answer (score 0):

for me your time is 200sec and i have checked it.

you increase by one and wait 50ms before next increment

so 4000 * 50 = 200000ms  -> 200s to join the value 4000

if you increase by 50 you'll have 4s

if you increase by 40 you'll have 5s

the minimun interval for settimeout is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)

4ms for modern browser and 10ms for old browser

**4ms** -> *16sec* to join 4000, **10ms** -> *40sec* to join 4000

Comment: i got your point. But what change do i need to to in my script?

Comment: you have to play with the time interval and/or the value to add..